# Why do Spark jobs fail with org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0 in speculation mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running a Spark job with in a speculation mode. I have around 500 tasks and around 500 files of 1 GB gz compressed. I keep getting in each job, for 1-2 tasks, the attached error where it reruns afterward dozens of times (preventing the job to complete).

> org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0

Any idea what is the meaning of the problem and how to overcome it?

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$1.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$1.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getServerStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$.fetch(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.FlatMappedRDD.compute(FlatMappedRDD.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Have you seen any `LostExecutor` INFO messages? Can you check web UI's Executors page and see how executors behave, esp. GC-wise?

Comment: Getting the same error in a Databricks High concurrency cluster

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Yes, my Executor failed with similar error

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This happened to me when I gave more memory to the worker node than it has. Since it didn't have swap, spark crashed while trying to store objects for shuffling with no more memory left.

Solution was to either add swap, or configure the worker/executor to use less memory in addition with using MEMORY_AND_DISK storage level for several persists.

Comment: If you have a resource on node (memory) you can try increasing spark executor memory. I will try that first if you are also concern about performance.

Comment: Hi @Joren this is not a competition. OP problem is executor not having enough memory to store shuffle output. What worked for you is not decreasing executor memory but using MEMORY_AND_DISK storage level which eliminates memory limitation of executor. Also OP doesn't say about how much resource he has for executor.

Comment: I have the same problem and I have tried methods like increasing executor memory, increasing repartitions amount , freeing more physical memory. And sometimes it worked while sometimes didn't. I found that this only happened in shuffle read phase and I'd like to ask that where can I set the StorageLevel?

Comment: I optimized my data structure and fixed it. I just changed HashMap into a byte[] which was serialized by protostuff

Comment: Try to change spark.driver.overhead.memory and spark.executor.overhead.memory to a value more that 384(Default) and it should work. You can use either 1024 MB or 2048 MB.

Comment: NB. these options are `spark.driver.memoryOverhead` and `spark.executor.memoryOverhead` as of Spark 2.3 and 2.4 (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/configuration.html#application-properties). But if you're running 2.4 on Kubernetes then there is also a `spark.kubernetes.memoryOverheadFactor` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/running-on-kubernetes.html#spark-properties) that seems to be used instead of the generic ones.

Answer (score 21):

The error arises when there is a lot of data in a particular spark partition. The way to solve this is to do the following steps:

1. Increase the number of shuffle-partitions:  --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=<some-high-number-lets say 200>
2. In normal cases the number of partitions should be set to number of executors * number of cores per executor  . But this kind of partitioning scheme will be problematic if we have huge amount of data. See the example below.

Suppose we had the following data and we had three executors with 1 core each , so the number of partitions(physical-partitions) in this case would be 3

```
 Data:  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,13,16,19,22

 Partitions:  1,2,3 
 Distribution of Data in Partitions (partition logic based on modulo by 3)

          1-> 1,4,7,13,16,19,22
          2-> 2,5,8
          3->3,6,9
 From above we can see that there is data skew, partition 1 is having more 
 data than the rest
 
 Now lets increase the number of partitions to : number of executors * number 
 of cores per executor*2 = 6 (in our example. These 6 partitions will be 
 logical partitions.Now each executor will be having 2 logical partitions 
 instead of 1 .Data partitioning will be based on modulo 6 instead of 3.

 Partitions of data in each executor:

        1->(0,1)->1,6,7,13,19
        2->(2,3)-->2,3,8,9
        3->(4,5)->4,5,16,22
The increase in logical partitions leads to fair partitioning.
```

3. The next thing you can do after increasing the number of shuffle partitions is
   to decrease the storage part of the spark memory if you are not persisting or
   caching any dataframe. By default the storage part is 0.5 and execution part
   is also 0.5 . To reduce the storage part you can set in your spark-submit
   command the following configuration

   ```
       --conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.3
   ```

4.) Apart from the above two things you can also set executor overhead memory.
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2g

```
 This is off-heap memory that is used for Virtual Machine overheads, interned 
 strings etc.
```

5.) Apart from this , you can limit the number of files processed in a
particular microbatch by setting the maxFilesPerTrigger to a smaller
value say 10.

Comment: Thank you so much for this elaborate answer !

Comment: Why do you say "some-high-number-lets say 200" when 200 is the default? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Comment: Yeah the default value is 200 , I said its a high number because from the point of view of a person who is beginner in spark , that value is quite high if he is processing some small file with 100K records(say). Creating high number of shuffle partitions for small tasks is also not a good practice , since you may incur overhead costs

Comment: If container memory = executor memory + executor overhead, and storageFraction specifies how the executor memory is split between storage and execution, why would decreasing it increase the executor overhead?

Answer (score 15):

We had a similar error with Spark, but I'm not sure it's related to your issue.

We used `JavaPairRDD.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` on 100GB data and it kept failing similarly to your app. Then we looked at the Yarn logs on the specific nodes and found out that we have some kind of out-of-memory problem, so the Yarn interrupted the execution. Our solution was to change/add `spark.shuffle.memoryFraction 0` in `.../spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`. That allowed us to handle a much larger (but unfortunately not infinite) amount of data this way.

Comment: Is it really "0" or was that a typing error? What is the logic behind that, to force it to spill permanently to disk?

Comment: @Virgil Yes. We made some tests. The closer we were to zero the larger the processable amount got. The price was 20% of time.

Comment: Interesting, I also reduce spark.shuffle.memoryFraction to zero but got more errors in a row. (Namely: MetadataFetchFailedException and FetchFailedException intermittenly) It should become a bug/issue if "all-spill" has less error than "partially-spill".

Answer (score 12):

I got the same issue on my 3 machine YARN cluster. I kept changing RAM but the issue persisted. Finally I saw the following messages in the logs:

```
17/02/20 13:11:02 WARN spark.HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 2 with no recent heartbeats: 1006275 ms exceeds timeout 1000000 ms
17/02/20 13:11:02 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on 1worker.com: Executor heartbeat timed out after 1006275 ms
```

and after this, there was this message:

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 67
```

I modified the properties in spark-defaults.conf as follows:

```
spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms 7200000
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 7200000
spark.network.timeout 7200000
```

That's it! My job completed successfully after this.

Comment: In the spark docs, it is said: `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval should be significantly less than spark.network.timeout`. So, setting both of those to same value might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 5):

in the Spark Web UI, if there is some info like `Executors lost`, then you have to
check the yarn log, make sure whether your container has been killed.

If the container was killed, it is probably due to the lack of memory.

How to find the key info in yarn logs? For example, there might be some warnings like this:

```
Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 2.5 GB of 2.5 GB physical memory used. 
Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

In this case, it suggests you should increase `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this error increasing the allocated memory in executorMemory and driverMemory. You can do this in HUE selecting the Spark Program which is causing the problem and in properties -> Option list you can add something like this:

```
--driver-memory 10G --executor-memory 10G --num-executors 50 --executor-cores 2
```

Note values of the parameters will vary depending on you cluster and dataset size.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was doing some windowing on large data (about 50B rows) and getting a boat load of

> `ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray:54` - Reached spill threshold of 4096 rows, switching to `org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter`

In my logs. Obviously 4096 can be small on such data size... this led me to the following JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21595

And ultimately to the following two config options:

- `spark.sql.windowExec.buffer.spill.threshold`
- `spark.sql.windowExec.buffer.in.memory.threshold`

Both default to 4096; I raised them much higher (2097152) and things now seem to do well. I'm not 100% sure this is the same as the issue raised here, but it's another thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (standalone cluster) the exception was thrown because the file system of some Spark slaves was filled 100%. Deleting everything in the `spark/work` folders of the slaves solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but I searched many answers which can not solve my problem. eventually, I debug my code step by step. I find the problem that caused by the data size is not balanced for each partition , leaded to `MetadataFetchFailedException` that in `map` stage not `reduce` stage . just do `df_rdd.repartition(nums)` before `reduceByKey()`

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution wat take a look into the code and realize we where using a repartition(1) to save a really big table =|.