# how to set spark RDD StorageLevel in hive on spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

In my hive on spark job , I get this error :

*org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0*

thanks for this answer ([Why do Spark jobs fail with org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0 in speculation mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901123/org-apache-spark-shuffle-metadatafetchfailedexception-missing-an-output-locatio)) , I know it may be my hiveonspark job has the same problem

since hive translates sql to a hiveonspark job, I don't how to set it in hive to make its hiveonspark job change from StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY to StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK ?

thanks for you help~~~~

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CACHE/UNCACHE [LAZY] Table <table_name>` to manage caching. [More details](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#caching).

If you are using DataFrame's then you can use the persist(...) to specify the StorageLevel. Look at [API here.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame).

In addition to setting the storage level, you can optimize other things as well. SparkSQL uses a different caching mechanism called Columnar storage which is a more efficient way of caching data (as SparkSQL is schema aware). There are different set of config properties that can be tuned to manage caching as described in [detail here (THis is latest version documentation. Refer to the documentation of version you are using).](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#performance-tuning)

- spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed
- spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize

Comment: thanks for your answer, but sparksql is the same as hiveonspark?  and I want to know that that spark job in HIVE ON SPARK, when data is out of memory, can that data write to disk? if can, it is default or I must set something?

Comment: I believe they both are same in the sense that they both use same runtime